# Measuring time between keystrokes in python

Tags: python

Using the following code:

```
   >>> import time
   >>> start = time.time()
   >>> end = time.time()
   >>> end - start
```

one can measure time between "start" and "end". What about measuring the time between specific keystrokes? Specifically, if a module was run and the user started typing something, how can python measure the time between the **first** keystroke and the **enter key**. Say I ran this script and it said: "Please enter your name, then press enter: ". I write Nico, and then press enter. How can I measure time between "N" and the enter key. This should be in seconds, and after pressing enter, the script should end.

Comment: This depends on *how* you actually get input from the user. If you're using Python's built-in `input()` (or `raw_input()`), you can't get at the individual keystrokes. If you're using [pygame](http://pygame.org) (for example), you can.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/694296/535275

Comment: @FGhilardi Actually, a friend showed me this (he didn't know how to do it), and I got really curious myself. No, not homework.

Answer (score 3):

This will work (on some systems!):

```
import termios, sys, time
def getch(inp=sys.stdin):
    old = termios.tcgetattr(inp)
    new = old[:]
    new[-1] = old[-1][:]
    new[3] &= ~(termios.ECHO | termios.ICANON)
    new[-1][termios.VMIN] = 1
    try:
        termios.tcsetattr(inp, termios.TCSANOW, new)
        return inp.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(inp, termios.TCSANOW, old)


inputstr = ''
while '\n' not in inputstr:
    c = getch()
    if not inputstr: t = time.time()
    inputstr += c
elapsed = time.time() - t
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408560/python-nonblocking-console-input) for nonblocking console input on other systems.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way you could do that is:

```
from time import time
begin = time.time()
raw_input() #this is when you start typing
#this would be after you hit enter
end = time.time()
elapsed = end - begin
print elapsed
#it will tell you how long it took you to type your name
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can you [msvcrt.kbhit()](http://docs.python.org/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit) to tell when a key has been pressed.  See http://effbot.org/librarybook/msvcrt.htm for a worked-out example.